# Sql order by and select top execution order

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by

I have the following query that returns an interval of records based on two values

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    a.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 5 
         ID, Name, CountryCode 
     FROM city 
     ORDER BY ID) a 
ORDER BY  
     ID desc
```

Result :

```
ID  Name                                CountryCode
5   Amsterdam                           NLD
4   Mazar-e-Sharif                      AFG
3   Herat                               AFG
```

This is the date from the city table :

```
ID  Name                            CountryCode
1   Kabul                               AFG
2   Qandahar                            AFG
3   Herat                               AFG
4   Mazar-e-Sharif                      AFG
5   Amsterdam                           NLD
6   Rotterdam                           NLD
7   Haag                                NLD
8   Utrecht                             NLD
9   Eindhoven                           NLD
10  Tilburg                             NLD
11  Groningen                           NLD
.   .                                   .
.   .                                   .
4076    Hebron                          PSE
4077    Jabaliya                        PSE
4078    Nablus                          PSE
4079    Rafah                           PSE
```

But when I remove the order by from the subquery I get a different result :

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    a.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 5 
         ID, Name, CountryCode 
     FROM city) a 
ORDER BY 
     ID asc
```

Result :

```
ID      Name                                CountryCode
4079    Rafah                               PSE
4078    Nablus                              PSE
4077    Jabaliya                            PSE
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: What don't you get?  You have two different queries and they return two different result sets.  I honestly don't know where any confusion can arise.  One point of guidance:  always use `ORDER BY1 when you use `TOP`.

Comment: When I execute the two subquerys : 'SELECT TOP 5 ID,Name,CountryCode FROM city' and 'SELECT TOP 5 ID,Name,CountryCode FROM city order by ID'
I get the same result ! So why using them with the same parent query give us different results !

Comment: `top 5` without `order by` chooses 5 random records. if this 5 records are the ones you expected, its an accident

Comment: Because `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is unstable.  SQL results sets are *unordered* unless you explicitly specify an ordering.  Might take some getting used to, but that is how the language works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order by will happen first before the select top directive. Thus in the example you've given it will order by the id's then select the top 5 records. This is a sub-query so the outer query will then order those 5 records by ids descending and then select the top 3.

When you remove the order by within the sub-query, the top 5 directive will simply return the first 5 records it comes across. This may be affected by a clustered index if there's one on the table so if the ID is clustered it will likely give the same result but if it's something else like a created date that will affect the order the results are returned. Please note that it cannot be guaranteed on the order even taking a clustered index into account. Query Parallelism may also come into play.

Basically, check the clustered index on the table as this may indicate the order but cannot guarantee it. Hope that makes sense.